# gradle build html5 libgdx successful but index.html is an empty page

Tags: java, html, gradle, libgdx

I ran ./gradlew html:dist and it was successful (with some warnings). now when I open the index.html it loads empty page with one button. what could be the problem?

Comment: You can't just open the index.html. You need to deploy the war to a server like tomcat. Then navigate to the path. Something like http://localhost:8080/MyGame/index.html

Comment: it works, thanks :)

Comment: or you can run in debug mode by gradlew html:superdev command and you can goto http://localhost:8080/html/ to access game (you dont need other server to debug and test)